# Polygon area - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate the area of a polygon, but the code implemented by me doesn't work. Can someone help me with a better solution?

Here is my code:

```
ar :: (Float,Float,Float)-> Float
ar (v1,v2,v3) = let a=distBetween v1 v2
        b=distBetween v2 v3
        c=distBetween v3 v1
        s=0.5*(a+b+c)
        in sqrt (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))

distBetween :: (Float,Float)->(Float,Float)->Float
distBetween (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt ((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2^2))
```

And this is my error:

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : distBetween v1 v2
*** Term           : v2
*** Type           : Float
*** Does not match : (Float,Float)
```

Comment: Note that this is probably a lousy way to calculate the area of a triangle. I'm no expert, but I think you'll probably get more precise results much more quickly by taking the magnitude of the cross product of `p2-p1` with `p3-p1`.

Answer (score 2):

`distBetween` works on two pairs of `Float`s, but `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` are all just single `Float`s.  If you had

```
-- Just creates an alias for `(Float, Float)`, since otherwise it'd be a lot of typing
type Point = (Float, Float)
```

Then you can write this as

```
distBetween :: Point -> Point -> Float
distBetween (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt $ (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2
-- You also had a typo in your distance function here    ^

ar :: (Point, Point, Point) -> Float
ar (v1, v2, v3) =
    let a = distBetween v1 v2
        b = distBetween v2 v3
        c = distBetween v3 v1
        s = 0.5 * (a + b + c)
    in sqrt $ s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)
```

Then it will compile just fine.  Since you had told the compiler that `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` were all just `Float`s, it just couldn't match that with `(Float, Float)` as needed for the arguments to `distBetween`.

Comment: Right, except `Float` [shouldn't be used at all](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point) (or, only as a space optimisation in unboxed arrays).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'd say that's a bit beyond the scope of this question, but yes, `Double` would be a better choice here.

Comment: Isn't this a `RealFloat` thing?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, `Float` is also the way to go if you're implementing something specifically tuned for single-precision floating point (e.g., from a numerical algorithms cookbook), but that certainly does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @dfeuer: it might, but really you can only get any significant performance benefit from float when running on a 32-bit / RISC processor. On x86-64, only vectorised instructions (SSE etc.) can give `Float` much of a boost; I think GHC starts being able to benefit from this, but it's still not something you'd consider before unboxing your arrays.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I wasn't talking about speed; I was talking about precision. If an algorithm is specifically designed for `Float` (e.g., with specific corrections for the expected rounding), it may not work properly with `Double`.

Comment: @dfeuer: well – somebody who implements algorithms like that should surely be aware of all subtleties and not heed any so basic advice. (Apart from that: in many of these cases you'll probably get better results if you throw away all of the corrections and switch to `Double`.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, true though that last bit may be, it may not always be obvious where the corrections are that you need to throw away!